# Layout Constraint issues with 2 side by side UILabels

Tags: xcode, uilabel, nslayoutconstraint

I have 2 UILabels side by side. The one on the right grows as the content inside changes (using sizeToFit) and when it grows, the one on the left should shrink and truncate if needed.

Here are the current constraints I have:

### The left label:

```
Leading space to superview: 8
Width <= 156
Top space to superview: 0
Height: 32
Trailing space to right label: 8
```

### The right label:

```
Trailing space to superview: 8
Width >= 0
Top space to superview: 0
Height: 32
Leading space to left label: 8
Leading space to superview <= 172
```

Using what I have here the right label will grow as it should, but the left label will not shrink and truncate the text inside. What am I doing wrong?

Edit: Both labels should have a static height. The right labels width should grow and the left labels width should shrink.

Comment: What is maximum size of right Label?

Comment: There shouldn’t be a max size on the right label, unless I have to have one?

Comment: What happen when right label have long(more than screen width) text?

Comment: At that point it should truncate the text inside I suppose.

Comment: Are you using storyboard?

Comment: Set height of left label as Height >= 32

Comment: Yes I’m using storyboard. And I don’t want the height to change ever.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For growing and shrink constraints each UIView have this methods:

```
contentCompressionResistancePriorityForAxis:// For setup shrink constraints
contentHuggingPriorityForAxis:// For setup growing constraints
```

Don't forget of priority.

p.s. Storyboards have same fields in params for each view.

Comment: Thank you so much, I always wondered what those settings were and never touched them. I did upvote your answer but I'm too new for it to go public :)

Comment: @eskimo You are welcome, you can accept answer if it help for you.